# Posting link appear on my wall, but not my news feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink

I'm attempting to post a link to my news feed, although currently it only appears on my wall. It does appear on the news feed of my friends which I want it to, it just doesn't show on my news feed.

I've tried posting to both me/feed and me/links

The fields I'm specifying are message and link, where message is just some text like "test" and link is the link to the page I'm trying to share.

I have gotten it to appear on my news feed a few times, but then on subsequent posts it no longer appeared. Does anyone have some information as to what may be happening or something to test out?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's related to the change they made related to sharing. They inserted the concept of implicit/explicit sharing.

Please, have a look [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/explicit_sharing/)

Comment: It could be, but that's mainly with the Actions part of the Graph API from what I understand.